# Is this a known pr-str/keyword bug in clojure?

Tags: clojure

Here's my clojure data:

```
{:local/contacts-capability contacts-capability}
```

pr-str gives me this:

```
#:local{:contacts-capability #uuid "00000000-0000-4000-8000-000000000003"}
```

I pass this over to clojurescript and when I read it, I get:

```
Uncaught Error: Could not find tag parser for :local in ("simpleArk.arkRecord.Ark-record" "uuid/Timestamp" "inst" "js" "queue" "uuid" "miMap/MI-map" "tailrecursion.priority-map" "simpleArk.rolonRecord.Rolon-record")
    at Function.cljs.reader.reader_error.cljs$core$IFn$_invoke$arity$variadic (reader.cljs:71)
    at cljs$reader$reader_error (reader.cljs:69)
    at cljs$reader$maybe_read_tagged_type (reader.cljs:613)
    at cljs$reader$read_dispatch (reader.cljs:260)
    at cljs$reader$read_delimited_list (reader.cljs:233)
    at cljs$reader$read_vector (reader.cljs:280)
    at cljs$reader$read (reader.cljs:464)
    at cljs$reader$read_string (reader.cljs:477)
    at console$client$display_property (client.cljs:366)
    at console$client$explore_BANG_ (client.cljs:404)

Dependencies:

[org.clojure/clojure "1.9.0-alpha10"  :scope "provided"]
[org.clojure/clojurescript "1.9.198"]
```

Comment: I'll note that when I add a second entry to the map, everything is fine:

 {:fix nil :local/contacts-capability contacts-capability}

Comment: Knowing the answer and being able to use it differ.

Upgraded clojurescript and reader dependencies. No change. :-(

build boot: https://github.com/rolonicArk/simpleArk/blob/master/build.boot

Comment: Turns out I also needed to upgrade clojure. :-)

Answer (score 2):

In Clojure 1.9, these two maps represent the same data:

```
#:foo{:bar 1 :baz 2}
{:foo/bar 1 :foo/baz 2}
```

If all the keys in the map are keywords and have the same namespace, the former is a shorter way to represent the latter. See here: http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJ-1910

I suspect that this is currently not supported in ClojureScript.

Comment: That's what I figured. I was just wondering if it is currently supported. I dislike having to change dependency versions in the middle of developing a project, but this is a serious incompatibility!

Comment: Jeremy, that is the perfect answer. Thanks!

Comment: Note that namespace map literal syntax printing is (as of Clojure 1.9.0-alpha14) off by default, except in the REPL where it is on. You can explicitly turn it off at the REPL with `(set! *print-namespace-maps* false)` or you can `(binding [*print-namespace-maps* false] ...)` around whatever printing code you have.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with using such an old version of clojure script. Later versions do fix this. See https://github.com/ptaoussanis/sente/issues/241